# How to create a functionality like a 'magnifying glass' on a html element/tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a simple div (id="one") , when user hover it , I need the div to get bigger and the nested text as well. The idea is getting the feeling of looking through 'magnifying glass'.Can't use plugins, I don't know how to start... Is it possible ?

```
//css
.one{
height:100px;
width:100px;

}

//html
<div id="one">
Another one bites the dust
</div>
```

Comment: did you tried anything?

Comment: looked on google didn't found something close to my need.. :(

Comment: did you try css `:hover`?? Question is overly broad since expected results are unknown

Comment: hover is not a problem the problem is how to enlarge the text and the div together, maybe it is easy and I didn't notice it.. I don't know where to start :/

Comment: @charlietfl - what is overly broad ?

Comment: @Damkulul: Something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/55s4jg5z/)?

Comment: @SyedAliTaqi, close but to be specific, when the mouse is hover the div not all the div is enlarge, only the part that the mouse is on, just like 'magnifying glass', is it possible ?

Comment: clone the same element and add css zoom

Comment: You can use http://stackoverflow.com/q/4912092/1529630 to make an screenshot int a canvas, and then manipulate that.

Comment: here's a fiddle to get you started http://jsfiddle.net/6km0z3ak/ I suggest you come back wit a more specific question

Comment: Ok thank you, I will start with that..